# Pagination Laravel Problems

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

All code from laravel documentation:
Controller:

```
public function search() {
    $request = Request::all();
    $name = $request['name'];
    $result = Driver::where('vendor', $name)->paginate(25);
    return view('driver_search', [
        '_keywords' => $name ?: '',
        'query' => request('name'),
        'result' => $result,

    ]);
}
```

View:

```
<tbody>
  {% for driver in result %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{ driver.vendor }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ driver.name }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ driver.os }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ driver.version}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ driver.size}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#">Download</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}

                </tbody>
            </table><!-- end table -->
        </div>

    </form>

    {{ result.links()|raw }}
```

The problem with varriable Name:
when pagination on 1 page it's ok and have this string in browser http://ddrivers/search?name=Nvidia
BUT when i click 2 or 3 or eny 1 want, i loose my name varriable and get error Undefined index: name and in my browser link looks like http://ddrivers/search?page=2
How to save Name varriable for all pagination?
If i delete |raw in view pagination displays as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to append the request params to the paginate call.

```
$result = Driver::where('vendor', $name)->paginate(25)->append(Request::all());
```